# If a tag synonym is made, do you get the badge?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, badges

The taxonomist badge is awarded to you if a tag you created is used 50 times. It is my understanding that if a tag synonym is made, no more questions are attributed to that tag.

If the tag synonym has 50 (+) questions tagged, are you awarded the Taxonomist badge?